# Complexe query with MongoID in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

My problem is the following:

I have a `Member` model with `last_visited_at` and `notified_at` attributes.

I want to select objects matching theses conditions:

( date_one < `last_visited_at` < date_two )
**AND**
( `notified_at` < date_one **OR** date_two < `notified_at` )

Which can also be written as :

date_one < `last_visited_at` 
**AND**
`last_visited_at` < date_two
**AND**
( `notified_at` < date_one **OR** date_two < `notified_at` )

---

Here is what I tried, but it didn't work:

I made sure one object was matching these conditions.

(MongoID, using Rails console)

```
Member.where(:last_visited_at => {"$lte" => date_one, "$gte" => date_two})
      .any_of(
              :notified_for_not_signing_in_at => {"$gte" => date_one},
              :notified_for_not_signing_in_at => {"$lte" => date_two})
      .first
```

it returns and error

Does anyone has an idea on how to solve that problem ?

Thanks for your help and for your time,

Comment: What was the error? Also your `any_of` hash has two entries for the same key, `:notified_for_not_signing_in_at`.

Answer (score 0):

[any_of](http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#any_of) has to be written like this (as hashes)

```
   .any_of( {:notified_for_not_signing_in_at => {"$gte" => date_one}},
            {:notified_for_not_signing_in_at => {"$lte" => date_two}})
```

not

```
any_of(
              :notified_for_not_signing_in_at => {"$gte" => date_one},
              :notified_for_not_signing_in_at => {"$lte" => date_two})
```